# SSE, interleave low and high words

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, sse

Is there a *single* SSE instruction to interleave high and low words of two registers into another register?  Eg:

```
r[63-0]   = a[64-127]
r[64-127] = b[63-0]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because there are no SSE shuffles that have two sources and a distinct destination.  However, you can do it if `r` is the same as `a`, with `shufpd`.  If you need to preserve the value of `a`:

```
movapd r, a
shufpd r, b, 1
```

On recent µarches, the `movapd` is free and handled in rename[*], so this effectively is a “single instruction", from the point of view of the execution core.

If AVX is available, you can use `vshufpd`.

[*] It’s possible to saturate this capability of rename, in which case the extra reg-reg moves will behave like normal port 0|1|5 operations—fortunately, real world code almost always has some bubbles on one of those ports, so the move tends to still be “free”.

Comment: +1 - I didn't know the vector units had this level of sophistication, though I shouldn't be surprised. I wonder, do recent micro-archs have large register files for SSE/AVX?

Comment: Maybe they have some debug registers and maintenance registers working in background to increase pipelining(controlled by cpu only?).

Comment: @BrettHale: yes, the physical AVX/SSE register file is about as large as the GPR register file is.

Comment: Just to note that `mov` instructions, even when eliminated by rename, aren't necessarily free - they don't take an execution port, but they still take an entry in the ROB and count against the all important limit of 4 fused-domain uops a cycle. Well designed code without long dependency chains, especially scalar code, can often hit this 4-uop limit given the wealth of execution units on recent CPUs, at which point movs are very much not free. AVX alleviates this somewhat by introducing 3-argument instructions, with a destination register separate from the two source regs.